# How to make a single clean formula where it enter periods in blank rows and also averages the rows with partially completed rolls?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If a category (i.e. row) doesn't contain any value for any year, replace the missing data with periods (.).

If a category contains partially missing data, fill the missing data using the average value of the category across different years.

If a cell doesn't contain missing data, retain its original value.

I tried the formula of: =IF(COUNTIF(C2:O2,"=IF(COUNTIFS($C2:$O2,"")=13,".",IF(C2="",AVERAGE($C2:$O2),C2))

The formula did not work for me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ircxm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula then drag down and across.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C2:$O2,"")=13,".",IF(C2="",AVERAGE($C2:$O2),C2))
```

[image]